# How long is the support period of Angular which is not Long-Term Support?

Tags: angular

Angular4.x was announced to support from October/2017 to October/2018 as Long-Term Support.
On the other hand, how long is the support period of Angular which it not Long-Term Support such as Angular2.x?

If next major version of Angular is released, support of before version of Angular will expire in no time?
Or will support 6 months as backward compatibility?

If there are some Reference URL, I would appreciate your teaching.

Comment: [Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641316) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019826) with "Updated url for Angular release schedule: https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most official doc for the angular release schedule / LTS. (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md)

There is no indication to how long v2.0.0 will be supported. If angular 4.0.0 will be supported until around the time of angular 7.0.0 release (October 2018), one might assume angular 2.0.0 will be supported until Angular 6.0.0 (March/April 2018). But, this is all speculation.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md

The LTS is for a year.
Version ^4.0.0 Long term support started October 2017 and will end October 2018.

Now the support for non LTS versions is only in between major releases, but there might not be breaking changes. Angular also aims to be backwards compatible to 1 major version backwards, this is mostly to lighten the burden of packages developers.